# How to Upload an image using BackgroundTransferService and get the server response?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to Upload image using wp7 BackgroundTransferService and get the server response ?

```
 var transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(new Uri(Global.profileUploadServerUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
            transferRequest.Method = "POST";
            transferRequest.UploadLocation = new Uri(@"/shared\transfers/file.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;
            transferRequest.Headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";
            transferRequest.TransferStatusChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transferRequest_TransferStatusChanged);
            transferRequest.TransferProgressChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transferRequest_TransferProgressChanged);

            BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);



static void transferRequest_TransferProgressChanged(object sender, BackgroundTransferEventArgs e)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

static void transferRequest_TransferStatusChanged(object sender, BackgroundTransferEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundTransferRequest request = sender as BackgroundTransferRequest;
    if (request.TransferStatus == TransferStatus.Completed)
    {
        BackgroundTransferService.Remove(request);
        if (request.StatusCode == 201)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Upload completed.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured during uploading. Please try again later." + request.StatusCode.ToString() + "/ " + request.TransferError);
        }
    }
}
```

image loading seems to pass, but the server returns status 206.
And how to get a response from the server?
Here looked example, but I did not understand it.
[In this example](http://olivierlefebvre.tumblr.com/post/9330062497/upload-using-backgroundservice-and-get-the-server), there is a line:

```
  request.DownloadLocation = new Uri (responsePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

That it is necessary to specify? if I do, it will specify the same url, it fails.
In general, the idea after unloading image server should return a response with a link to the image. But he will come out the answer 206.
How to get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from the [BackgroundTransferRequest.StatusCode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferrequest.statuscode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) topic on MSDN:

> This property contains the HTTP status code returned from the server
>   with which the request was initiated. **The status code indicating
>   success is 200 or 206**, depending on the server configuration. **Note
>   that this code** indicates whether the server could successfully
>   complete the request. It **does not indicate that the transfer was
>   successful. A successful transfer will have a TransferStatus of
>   Completed and TransferError will be null**.